# Create dataset from a folder of images and a txt file with labels

Tags: image-processing, pytorch, dataset, dataloader

I have two folders containing train and test images. And I have two files train.txt and test.txt containing the labels. I want to create a dataset for a PyTorch setting. I mean, I want to use DataLoader and I want the tuples (x_train, y_train) and (x_test, y_test). How can I do? Basically I think that in tensorflow I can use flow_from_dataframe, but in PyTorch?
As an example, in this image I show my pandas dataframe containing filenames and labels:
[image: dataframe]

EDIT:
I am trying with a custom dataset class:

```
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import os
import pandas as pd
from torchvision.io import read_image

class CoViDxDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, annotations_file, img_dir, transform=None, target_transform=None):
        self.img_labels = annotations_file
        self.img_dir = img_dir
        self.transform = transform
        self.target_transform = target_transform

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.img_labels)

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img_path = os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.img_labels.iloc[idx, 0])
        print(img_path)
        image = read_image(img_path)
        label = self.img_labels.iloc[idx, 1]
        if self.transform:
            image = self.transform(image)
        if self.target_transform:
            label = self.target_transform(label)
        return image, label

train_dataset = CoViDxDataset(train_df, train_path)
```

When I do `train_dataset[0]` I have this error:

```
train/ARDSSevere.png
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [84], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 train_dataset[0]

Input In [82], in CoViDxDataset.__getitem__(self, idx)
     17 img_path = os.path.join(self.img_dir, self.img_labels.iloc[idx, 0])
     18 print(img_path)
---> 19 image = read_image(img_path)
     20 label = self.img_labels.iloc[idx, 1]
     21 if self.transform:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/openfl/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/io/image.py:245, in read_image(path, mode)
    243 if not torch.jit.is_scripting() and not torch.jit.is_tracing():
    244     _log_api_usage_once(read_image)
--> 245 data = read_file(path)
    246 return decode_image(data, mode)

File ~/anaconda3/envs/openfl/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/io/image.py:47, in read_file(path)
     45 if not torch.jit.is_scripting() and not torch.jit.is_tracing():
     46     _log_api_usage_once(read_file)
---> 47 data = torch.ops.image.read_file(path)
     48 return data

RuntimeError: Expected a non empty file
```

where `train_path = 'train/'` and train_df is the image below:
[image: train_df]

Comment: loop over your dataset, read the label and images! this doc might help you https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/data_tutorial.html

Comment: @CasellaJr If you don't want to get into the headache of setting your own custom dataset via a class as in the docs in the comment above then I'd suggest the following:
1 - Create "positive" and "negative" folders in each of the train and test folders.

2 - Write a Python script (or manually/via OS) to loops over the csv and the images in the test/train folder to decide whether the current image should go to the "positive" or "negative" folder within.

3 - Load the train and test data in two lines of code via https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.datasets.ImageFolder.html